# Jquery Modification of SlideToggle

Tags: jquery, html

The below code keeps all "content_opener" open with "-" symbol. When user click on the "-", then that respective "content_opener" will be closed with "+" symbol.

Can anyone help me in changing this to: 1st "content_opener" to open and other "content_opener" to be closed. When user click on other closed "content_opener", it should be opened and the previously opened "content_opener" must be closed.

```
<div class="row standardContent racc_parent" data-expandall="">
    <div class="maincontent fullwidth racc columns content twelve large-12 medium-12">
        <div class="heading_opener">
            <span class="heading_title raccopen">
                       <h2>Purpose</h2>
                       </span>
        </div>
        <div class="content_opener">
            <p>purpose</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row standardContent racc_parent" data-expandall="">
    <div class="maincontent fullwidth racc columns content twelve large-12 medium-12">
        <div class="heading_opener">
            <span class="heading_title raccopen">
                       <h2>All stuff</h2>
                       </span>
        </div>
        <div class="content_opener">
            <p>All stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row standardContent racc_parent" data-expandall="">
    <div class="maincontent fullwidth racc columns content twelve large-12 medium-12">
        <div class="heading_opener">
            <span class="heading_title raccopen">
                       <h2>Things To Do</h2>
                       </span>
        </div>
        <div class="content_opener">
            <p>Things To Do</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content_opener').not('.content_open').show();
    $('.heading_opener').click(function(){
    var current_content = $(this).next('.content_opener');
    var current_heading = $(this).find('.heading_title');
    var heading_opener = $(this);
        $('.heading_title').not(current_heading).removeClass('raccopen');
        current_heading.toggleClass('raccopen');
        if(!heading_opener.hasClass('alt')){heading_opener.toggleClass('alt');current_content.slideToggle('fast');}
        else{current_content.slideToggle('fast', function(){
            heading_opener.toggleClass('alt');
        });
        }
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hide the element before showing it using `$('.content_opener').slideUp();` on click.

If you want to show only the content of first you can do `$('.content_opener').first().show();` and use `display: none;` on the others.

You can take a look at this **[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h41gwb9o/1/)** or just run the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content_opener').first().show();
  $('.heading_opener').click(function() {
    var current_content = $(this).next('.content_opener');
    var current_heading = $(this).find('.heading_title');
    var heading_opener = $(this);
    $('.content_opener').slideUp();
    $('.heading_title').not(current_heading).removeClass('raccopen');
    current_heading.toggleClass('raccopen');
    if (!heading_opener.hasClass('alt')) {
      heading_opener.toggleClass('alt');
      current_content.slideToggle('fast');
    } else {
      current_content.slideToggle('fast', function() {
        heading_opener.toggleClass('alt');
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.content_opener {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row standardContent racc_parent" data-expandall="">
  <div class="maincontent fullwidth racc columns content twelve large-12 medium-12">
    <div class="heading_opener">
      <span class="heading_title raccopen">
                       <h2>Purpose</h2>
                       </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content_opener">
      <p>purpose</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row standardContent racc_parent" data-expandall="">
  <div class="maincontent fullwidth racc columns content twelve large-12 medium-12">
    <div class="heading_opener">
      <span class="heading_title raccopen">
                       <h2>All stuff</h2>
                       </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content_opener">
      <p>All stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row standardContent racc_parent" data-expandall="">
  <div class="maincontent fullwidth racc columns content twelve large-12 medium-12">
    <div class="heading_opener">
      <span class="heading_title raccopen">
                       <h2>Things To Do</h2>
                       </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content_opener">
      <p>Things To Do</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working, but it is breaking my css code. I updated css code in below link. Can you help me to fix that to:
https://jsfiddle.net/h41gwb9o/2/

Comment: @user3781360, what do you mean by `is breaking my css code` ? I've put the original code you had and is the same `CSS`. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: When "content_opener" is open then "heading_opener" should be in blue color bar with minus symbol and when it is closed then "heading_opener" should be in silver color bar with plus symbol. Which is not happening now.

Comment: @user3781360, that does not happen with the original code you posted either. I don't see any `+` sign.

Comment: @user3781360, is this what you mean ?  https://jsfiddle.net/h41gwb9o/4/